# AngularJS localstorage performance problems

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, local-storage, ng-storage

I have performance problems with large objects in a single key when using ng-storage module (https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage).

The best example of this is having a text field with ng-model binded to localstorage variable. When you type on the text field, its lagging a lot.

Also when having a button and clicking it very fast (value +1) its lagging behind few numbers all the time.

Doing the same without ng-model, there are no delay.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this or should I design the app differently?

***UPDATE***

I ended up with a timer that fires a function which saves the data once in 30sec